# Fix CIFS permissions: files created via Windows have 777 permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, cifs

I have an HNAS that is hosting a CIFS share. Windows and Linux systems both have access to it. If a user creates a file on the share via Windows the file has 777 permissions on the Linux system.

How can I fix this?

All references I have found only refer to Samba or SMB.

Edit: I don't believe there is an smb.conf file on the HNAS. I looked int he normal locations and tried using the find command but no luck. I also don't think it was intended, even if it was there, for the smb.conf file on an HNAS to be modified as you are essentially modifying a core service. (Sorry if that doesn't make sense.)

Also for further clarification the HNAS uses CIFS to share with windows but NFS to share with linux.

Would this just require something like an ACL on the CIFS side so the file system on the HNAS or NFS knows how to equate the windows permissions to linux permissions?

Comment: CIFS is the new name for Samba. Old name for Samba was SMB.  All same same.  In the smb.conf, check the create mask and related options.

Comment: @ivanivan `CIFS` is the protocol; `Samba` is a server suite that speaks that protocol.  @Aradragoon can you tell us the specific model of your HNAS?  i suspect your solution will be configuring the HNAS properly; this question might be more appropriate to [sf].